# Why is dotnet ef not able to create a database against SQL Server Express?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, sql-server-express

I have gone through this ASP.Net MVC Core tutorial at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql.
And I am able to use dotnet migrations to create the database against the localDb with this connection string in the appsettings.json file:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-MvcMovie-3005e0f3-42f4-4163-94cc-f794a05e8b91;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

Now I want to point it to SQL Server Express to see if I can work from there and SSMS.

So now I use this in the appsettings.json file:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
   "SqlExpressConnection": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MvcMovieDb1;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

And in StartUp.ConfigureServices(), change:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

to

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlExpressConnection")));
```

Then in the command prompt run:

> dotnet ef database update

But now I get:
"CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

How can I give ef permission to create the database?
Is there a login/password parameter that the dotnet ef can use if I create a login with CREATE Permissions?

---

Well it seems I don't have DB permissions like I thought.

I just did a test to add a db from within SSMS and I don't seem to have CREATE privilege
"CREATE DATABASE Permission denied in database 'master'.

I am in SSMS under my computer admin login account.
And I startup SSMS using windows authentication.
So the top connection node looks like:
FullComputerName\SQLExpress(SQL Server 11.0.6020 - CompanyDomainName\Samuel).

The Windows Authentication login is in the form: CompanyDomainName\Samuel.
I don't see my CompanyDomainName\Samuel account under Computer Manager - Users.
Not sure how I am able to login to the computer with this account.
How can I add this account as a login under Security Logins?

Comment: I suggest use a sql user and password, and the sql user must have sufficient permission to create a db, I use sa user and it works for me. Note I'm not recommending use sa user in production. In that case I would create the db ahead of time and set a user with just enough permission on the db

Comment: Did you install SQLexpress yourself? Maybe you forgot to add your local account as administrator during the installation? (point 9 in https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143722(v=sql.90).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Or you use different user than one used for installation? Maybe alternatively you can also use localdb, it runs in a local process https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx

Comment: I just did a test to add a db from within SSMS and I don't seem to have CREATE privilege
"CREATE DATABASE Permission denied in database 'master'.

I am in SSMS as my computer admin login account.
The login is in the form: CompanyDomainName\samuel

Answer (score 1):

Your local Windows account `CompanyDomainName\Samuel` is the SQLExpress administrator. It means you are admin of SQLExpress when you are logged on Windows.

The `Integrated security=true` is used to connect to SQL Server with the Windows account, but it doesn't work because IIS (or Kestrel or any web server) will use a different Windows user account.

You have two options :

- add the Windows user account of you web server in `Security/Logins`, and check `Windows authentication`
  [image]
- or create a new login with `SQL Server authentication`, and update you connection string to use it instead
  `"Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MvcMovieDb1;User Id=dbUserName;Password=thePassword"`

(note : if you choose this last solution, you should be aware of potential security issues if you store password in your source code. [Read this page for more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets))

Comment: Sorry - I don't think this answer is correct.  I did not install SQL EXPRESS so I am not the admin. I forgot they gave us a new laptop a while back and I did not get to install it this time and they just did not add my Domain Account in there to do anything.  And that leaves me not knowing the sa account password.  Does anyone know how to reset that in this situation by the way?  I'll probably have to uninstall it and reinstall (latest version from 2012 to 2016).

Comment: You don't have to uninstall and re-install. Have you created a new db user as glacasa suggested? If not create a new one and provide that new user with db_owner role.

Comment: This answer worked for me - but it's worth noting that createdb is a one-time process, so using the username/pw for a specific account that can create the db doesn't even have to be saved in code. After you run the initial createdb, you change the connection back to "Integrated Security=True", and you're set.

Answer (score 1):

I was never going to have priveledges since who ever built this laptop and installed SQL Server (2012) did it under their account.  So I installed SQL Server Express Advances 2014 and SSMS 2014.
Now I can create DBs directly in SSMS 2014.

In appsettings.json I created this second connection string and updated it in Startup.cs to reflect the "SQLEXPRESS2014" conn string.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-MvcMovie-3005e0f3-42f4-4163-94cc-f794a05e8b91;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
"SqlExpressConnection": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS2014;Database=MvcMovie;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

}

Then I ran

```
>dotnet ef database update
```

Everything is good for me now.